# Custom Facebook like button android v4

Tags: android, facebook

I want to create my custom facebook like button but with different text and image.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting the actual help from  this Url :

https://github.com/shamanland/facebook-like-button

Please Reply Weather you implemented or not From this Link.